# How does JSON.stringify automagically convert moment objects to iso strings?

Tags: javascript, json, momentjs, stringify

I'm curious how libs like [moment](https://momentjs.com/), automagically convert from objects to strings when `JSON.stringify` is called on that object.

Example test in moment: https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/3147fbc486209f0b479dc0b29672d4c2ef39cf43/src/test/moment/format.js#L144-L146

Here's some example code that i'm curious how it works

```
const moment = require('moment');
const duration = moment.duration(1374);
console.log('duration = ', duration); // Prints a duration object
console.log('JSON.stringify(duration) = ', JSON.stringify(duration)); // Prints a string such as `P0D1T0H3` <-- Note: Not exact value, just similar format
```

Comment: Pretty sure JSON.stringify casts all non-primitives as strings, so custom toString method is the likely answer.

Comment: @JaredSmith no, it turns them into JSON :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> If the value has a toJSON() method, it's responsible to define what data will be serialized.

From [moment](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/1fea64ebc6d312097fa82e9393ced1ca8372bcd5/src/lib/duration/prototype.js):

> ```
> proto.toJSON         = toISOString;
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If an object has a `.toJSON()` method, `JSON.stringify()` will call that before attempting to do it's own thing with the object.

Date objects, and apparently Moment wrapper objects, have `.toJSON()` that calls `.toISOString()`.